# ActionFilter not firing at Method level in Base Controller...works at Class Level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

MVC 4
I have an action filter that I want applied only to the Index and Edit methods in my base controller, but the action filter does not fire when I apply it to the Index and Edit methods.  It DOES work however if I apply the filter at the class level.

Base Controller:

```
//[SetAreaControllerFilter]  <------ does fire here
    public class BaseControllerSingle<TRepository, TViewModelSingle> : BaseController

    [SetAreaControllerFilter]  <----- doesn't fire here
    public ActionResult IndexBase(TViewModelSingle viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        ViewBag.Header = pageTitle;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Derived class call to base:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ItemViewModel viewModel = _manageItemsAppServ.CreateNewViewModel(CurrentCompanyId);
            viewModel.DDLOptions = _manageItemsAppServ.CreateFilterOptionsViewModel(CurrentCompanyId);
            return base.IndexBase(viewModel, "Manage Materials");
        }
```

Action Filter:

```
public class SetAreaControllerFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter 

 {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
          //Set variable to be used by view and partials
           dynamic viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;

           viewBag.AreaName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]; //used by OTIS.Core.js to create links
           viewBag.ControllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]; //used by Toolbar adn OTIS.Core.js to create links
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it appears that there is NOT a way to apply a filter to an action in a base controller. You need to apply it at the class level or to the actions in the derived controller class. This does not seem like it should be this way, but no one has been offer a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

First, the base ActionFilterAttribute class already implements both the IActionFilter and IResultFilter interfaces and inherits from the Filter class.  IActionFilter us redundant.

Now, to answer your question, the Action being executed and to which filters are applied is Index.  IndexBase is just a method of type ActionResult, not an Action.  Therefore no ActionFilter will be triggered.

Just apply your filter to Index.  If you want a global filter, register it in FilterConfig:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new SetAreaControllerFilter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but does that mean there is no way to apply a filter for a specific action at the base controller level? I was trying to avoid decorating every controller with this and just doing it once in the base controller.

Comment: Yes - if you want a global filter, register it in FilterConfig.cs - updated answer

Comment: and once registered as a global filter, it would be called when IndexBase is called?

Comment: no - global filters are called on the action.  Since your filter implements OnActionExecuting, it will be called as any action begins.  IndexBase is just a method, not an action.